# How to modify WordPress or its underlying PHP to make RESTful API calls?

Tags: php, wordpress

Me and a couple of other people have put together an e-commerce site (I will not tell you the url because I am not here to promote it).  The web site is a  wordpress website(yes, the plugins have gotten that advanced now). The distributor, the people who actually make and send out the products, have made is such that I can communicate with them via RESTFUL API calls.  I have looked at some of the wordpress plug-ins for this and it seems that they will allow me only to do command-line web server calls to my website from outside.

How can I code my website to make the calls to the REST API of another website?  I do not know where the best place is to go to start researching this?  Maybe I need to hard code the PHP of my website somewhere?

I am just look for a starting point and advice at this point.

Comment: It would much easier if you try to explain a little deeper. Give a simple scenario of what you want accomplished.

Comment: too much guess work to even try and answer. But offhand include a rest call (prob curl library) in your purchase confirmation script.

Comment: I will return to this topic in a few weeks.